# Mysql + PHP for "Wilson Score Interval" with time gravity

Tags: php, mysql, ranking, voting-system

I'd like to implement a ranking system for news in a webpage.

And I'd need guidance on:

- My approach. Is it correct? Is it crazy/stupid?.
- If is correct, on its implementation.

Relevant information:

- I'm using PHP, MYSQL with Code igniter.
- User can up_vote and down_vote the webpage news.
- The news would be ranked by its "Wilson Score Interval" with slight modifications:

  - Time gravity (newest news are likely to appear first).
  - However the time decay would stop after 48 hours (the gravity effect for the news would be the same after 48 hours).

**Approach**
I'd like to do everything via Mysql:

- I'd store the Time Gravitated Wilson Score (TGWS)- the one obtained in the gravityRating function - into the news_table.
- I'd create a trigger. I'd recalculate just the TGWS for the new's row being up/down voted.
- I'd create an event. Every 30 minutes it would update the TGWS of news published in the last 48 hours. (After 48 hours, the score should not change until a vote is issued so is not need to re-calculate news older than 48 hours).

Does it make sense?

**Implementation**
Ok. I know the code in PHP (see below).
But how do I port over Wilson Score code to Mysql? That's possible? Is it already done somewhere?
I've already created Triggers, Functions, Event and Procedures in Mysql, but I don't know how to port this one.

Thanks!

```
<?php

class Rating
{
  public static function ratingAverage($positive, $total, $power = '0.05')
  {
    if ($total == 0)
      return 0;

    $z = Rating::pnormaldist(1-$power/2,0,1);
    $p = 1.0 * $positive / $total;
    $s = ($p + $z*$z/(2*$total) - $z * sqrt(($p*(1-$p)+$z*$z/(4*$total))/$total))/(1+$z*$z/$total);
    return $s;
  } 

  public static function pnormaldist($qn)
  {
    $b = array(
      1.570796288, 0.03706987906, -0.8364353589e-3,
      -0.2250947176e-3, 0.6841218299e-5, 0.5824238515e-5,
      -0.104527497e-5, 0.8360937017e-7, -0.3231081277e-8,
      0.3657763036e-10, 0.6936233982e-12);

    if ($qn < 0.0 || 1.0 < $qn)
      return 0.0;

    if ($qn == 0.5)
      return 0.0;

    $w1 = $qn;

    if ($qn > 0.5)
      $w1 = 1.0 - $w1;

    $w3 = - log(4.0 * $w1 * (1.0 - $w1));
    $w1 = $b[0];

    for ($i = 1;$i <= 10; $i++)
      $w1 += $b[$i] * pow($w3,$i);

    if ($qn > 0.5)
      return sqrt($w1 * $w3);

    return - sqrt($w1 * $w3);
  }

    public static function gravityRating($positive, $total, $time, $power = '0.05')
  {
    if ($total == 0)
      return 0;
    return (Rating::ratingAverage($positive, $total, $power) / pow($time,0.5)); //para reducir el valor del tiempo solo dividir time por algo.
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm currently looking into get a similar Wilson Score with a time  variable. There is a quite interesting article about this where they have a logarithmic decrease of the score while time goes by. http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588 Unfortunately I have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question makes any sense. In reality there isn't such thing like time gravity and also if you just want to show the latest news you can sort the news. It's also true that the wilson intervall has nothing to do with time thus calculating every 30 minutes a wilson intervall doesn't change anything.

Comment: I want to order considering both, the timing and the votes. As for example does reddit. And my mistake, what I want to store is not the WS but the WS + gravity effect (score calculated on the gravityRating function), which will change with the time.

Comment: @JuanCarlos: If you want to order both you must define some function (x,y)=z. If you just adding a linear value to the average rating that doesn't seems to work. When your function is useful then you can keep it. Otherwise read my answer.